Переворачиваются полигоны при импорте из Blender (я думаю)

На гифке видно как отображается моделька импортированная из блендера.
Rendering Mode у материала Fade (на Transparent такая же проблема).
На Opaque отображается верно, но я хочу сделать плавное исчезновение монетки, поэтому мне нужен Fade.
В Блендере нормали настроены правильно.


Blender тут не причём и полигоны тут не причём, никто не перевёрнут, дело в шейдере и ты буквально сам это пишешь и да, этот именно так и выглядит, полигоны видны сквозь полигоны, а не то что ты себе представил. Шейдеры это ОЧЕНЬ большая тема, а Transparent так ваще, открывая дверь нагой с руками в карманах не войдёшь. Fade шейдер очень сложная штука.

@Yaroslav неужели нельзя сделать обычное исчезновение объекта как то по простому?

То что у тебя не бъет по производительности, но разница между желаемым огромна. Самый просто и экономичный вариант это использовать текстуру шума и шейдерTransparent/Cutout.

Выглядит cutout dissolve эффект так, а если поиграть с шейдерграфом то так.

А то, что ты изначально хотел получить... попробуй вспомнить игры, где ты такое виде... не обсобо получается? То-то и оно!

Если передняя стенка объекта полупрозрачная, то что вы увидите за ней? Другие поверхности того же объекта. Но исчезновение предмета в кино сделано по другому: объект не становится более прозрачным, более прозрачным становится его изображение на экране. И вместо кишок монетки вы видите задний план сцены. Так что шейдером вы не обойдётесь.
